# Handle blank input line and check string is number in Java

Tags: java, string, input

If I am asking for user input:

1. How can I handle a blank input (e.g. for a name of a person)?
2. How can I ensure that a String input required to be a number is actually a number?

Comment: This should be two separate questions.

Comment: You are going to need to clarify your question. How are you asking for user input? Via what means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if the input String length == 0, to check for numbers you can do this

```
try
{
    int num = Integer.parseInt(string);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Invalid number");
}
```

Sorry if the formatting is a little off but my browser isn't playing well today.

Comment: thanks RC, Linux doesn't play nice sometimes with nightly builds of Chromium and FF4

Answer (score 3):

http://commons.apache.org/lang/

```
  org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isBlank(str);
  org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils.isNumber(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1) You should decide on what to do (e.g. display error message)

Q2)

```
try 
{

  double d = Double.parseDouble(yourString);

} catch (NumberFormatException e) 
{
 //not number 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (input.trim().length() == 0) {
    // input is empty
}

try {
    Integer.parseInt(input);
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    // input is not a valid int
}
```

for the code (note the `trim()`)

Answer (score 0):

To test if a string is empty:

```
if (name.isEmpty())
```

Sometimes users enter extraneous spaces. You can work around that by trimming them out, so a string like `" "` still gets flagged as empty:

```
if (name.trim().isEmpty())
```

To test if a string is a number, parse it and see if you get an exception:

```
try {
    int value = Integer.valueOf(string);

    System.out.println("value is " + value);
}
catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
    System.out.println("not a valid number: " + string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `try..catch` method won't work for me, so I chose another approach.

```
for(byte i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    if(string.charAt(i) > 65) {
        isNtNumber = true;
    } 
}
```